Heap out of memory Angular Ckeditor 5
All I did was npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular, imported it in shared.module.ts
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
And after typing ng serve i get this error message after it finishes sealing...
Also RAM usage spikes up to 4 gigs more than usual...
What could be the cause of this error message?
I have tried deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json file, but nothing...

√ Compiled successfully.
⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4380:0000018D91386A30]   635576 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3769.1 (4135.9) -> 3769.1 (4135.9) MB, 3.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.069, current mu = 0.027) allocation failure;
[4380:0000018D91386A30]   635584 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3771.8 (4138.6) -> 3771.8 (4138.6) MB, 3.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.069, current mu = 0.027) allocation failure;
[4380:0000018D91386A30]   635589 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3772.9 (4139.7) -> 3772.9 (4139.7) MB, 3.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.069, current mu = 0.027) allocation failure;


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF61745D84F node_api_throw_syntax_error+174175
 2: 00007FF6173E0DA6 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCode::safepoint_table_offset+59926
 3: 00007FF6173E2A40 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCode::safepoint_table_offset+67248
 4: 00007FF617E8D604 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+116
 5: 00007FF617E78992 v8::Isolate::Exit+674
 6: 00007FF617CFA87C v8::internal::EmbedderStackStateScope::ExplicitScopeForTesting+124
 7: 00007FF617D07B5D v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1117
 8: 00007FF617D04BE7 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3367
 9: 00007FF617CF7317 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2039
10: 00007FF617D0DCD3 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath+2099
11: 00007FF617D0E57D v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath+93
12: 00007FF617D1DD40 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+816
13: 00007FF617A0EE85 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1349
14: 00007FF617F2B501 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558257
15: 00007FF617EDCF35 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+237285
16: 00007FF59B5FE6C6

This is angular version:
ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 18.20.4
Package Manager: npm 10.7.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.3.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1703.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      17.3.8
@angular-devkit/core               17.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         17.3.8
@angular/cdk                       17.3.10
@angular/cdk-experimental          16.2.6
@angular/cli                       17.3.8
@angular/material                  17.3.10
@angular/material-moment-adapter   17.3.10
@schematics/angular                17.3.8
ng-packagr                         17.3.0
rxjs                               7.8.1
typescript                         5.4.5
zone.js                            0.14.7



You should file a report at the github page.

Did you also install ckeditor5? On their documentation website it shows to install both the ckeditor5 AND @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular packages. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/installation/angular.html#quick-start
